# Magic Methods php, __call __get and __set?

Tags: php, get, set, call, magic-methods

my question is, say we have a class:

```
class SomeClass{

    private $someProperty;


    public function __call($name,$arguments){
        echo "Hello World";
}
```

Now when I say:

```
$object = new SomeClass();
$object->someMethod();
```

the __call method in my class will be called.

When I say

```
$object->getSomeProperty();
```

will __call again be called?
If so, what is __get and __set magic methods are for?

When I say

```
$object->someProperty;
```

then will __get($someProperty) be called? or will it be __set($someProperty) ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Anytime an inaccessible method is invoked `__call` will be called.

Anytime you try to read a property `__get` will be called, whether it's `echo $obj->prop;` or `$var = $obj->prop;`

And lastly, anytime you try to write to a property the `__set` magic method will be called.

Comment: so when I say $obj->prop __get is called but if it is $obj->prop = $something __set is called? And this is only true if prop is not public?

Comment: And you mean anytime a method that does not exists or is it really anytime a method is called __call is called?

Comment: `__set` is only called when you have an instance of an object. Setting variables inside of your class will not call `__set`. Regardless, private properties can't be accessed when you have an instance of an object, so yes, only public properties, when changed, will invoke `__set`. As for `__call`, it is only invoked when a method is inaccessible, so yes, when the method doesn't exist it will be invoked.

Comment: Can you please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571565/get-is-not-called-if-set-is-not-called-however-code-works

Answer (score 1):

> will __call again be called?

Yes.

> If so, what is __get and __set magic methods are for?

see below:

> When I say
>
> ```
> $object->someProperty;
> ```
>
> then will __get($someProperty) be called? or will it be
>   __set($someProperty) ?

`__get('someProperty')` because this expression is not an assignment.