# __get is not called if __set is not called, however code works?

Tags: php, get, set, magic-methods

Here is my code:

```
<?php

class SampleClass {

    public function __get($name){
        echo "get called";
        echo $name;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        echo "set called";
    }

}

?>
```

And my index file:

```
$object = new SampleClass();
$object->color = "black";
echo $object->color;
```

If I run this code as it is, here is the output:

```
set calledget calledcolor
```

However if I comment out

```
public function __set($name, $value) {
    echo "set called";
}
```

the part above (only this part), then the output will be:

```
black
```

So what happened here?

Comment: You've disabled the setter method, which is not longer outputting your message. Instead, it's displaying the natural value of your class property

Comment: @hohner: But why isn't `'get called'` being echoed?

Comment: @Koray Tugay Interesting problem. I can reproduce it

Comment: You created a public property by assigning a value to it directly. Hence magic get is no longer called.

Comment: @datasage Thats interesting!! I didn't knowed that one can create public properties from outside class... And that this behaviour can be influenced by just defining __get and __set(!)

Comment: Its one of the loosely typed aspects of PHP. You don't have to define a property before using it.

Comment: @datasage When do I create a public property by assigning a value to it directly? When the __set is commented out? If so, what happens when __set is not commented out?

Comment: @datasage Yes but note that just the precense of `__get()` and `__set()` will have influence on this behaviour. This is a side effect one should know about. Will search php.net if they have documentation on this

Comment: @KorayTugay when `__set` is not commented out, _nothing_ happens when you assign `$object->color = 'black'` (besides the `echo` inside `__set`), no property is created, no property is assigned, and this is the reason you don't get `black` echoed at the end of your output, even though you have an `echo $object->color`.

Comment: @lanzz So when __set is not commented out, __set is called, because color is an inaccessible field. But if there is no __set implementation in the class, __set is NOT called, because color is an accessible field?

Comment: @KorayTugay If there is no `__set` implementation in the class, `__set` is not called because _there is no `__set` implementation in the class_. In that case PHP just assumes (usually incorrectly) that you know what you're going, and just goes ahead and creates a brand new, public property in your instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an explanation of what is happening. In your first example. You never stored the value within the object, nor did a declared property exist.  This, `echo $object->color;` never actually does anything as nothing is returned from `__get`.

In your second example, you assigned a value to a property in your object. Since you did not declare the property in your object, it gets created by default as public. Since its public, `__get` is never called when accessing it.

Comment: note that just the precense of __get() and __set() will have influence on this behaviour. This is a side effect one should definetly know about. maybe a bug. Will search php.net if they have documentation on this

Comment: @hek2mgl Uh, the presence of `__get` and `__set` is what influences this behavior _by definition_. This is not a side-effect: when your `__set` magic method _doesn't_ assign anything _explicitly_, nothing gets assigned at all; this is the _whole purpose_ of the magic setter method, to control what is getting assigned and how.

Comment: and why `object->color` does **not** create a public property anymore. only when `__get`, `__set` are **just present**? This means: When those magic method are just present one cannot create public properties 'on the fly'.. I cannot find documention on this

Comment: @hek2mgl Because you have an existing `__set` method that is expected to handle that assignment. You need to explicitly assign `$this->$name = something` inside the `__set` method, in order to actually have any assignment done. You might want to update an internal array instead of a property; you might want to update a database record instead of a property; this is _for you to define_ inside your `__set` method. If automatic property creation continued to happen even when you have a `__set` method, then you'd lose all those proxy property patterns that you can implement with your magic methods

Comment: @hek2mgl The only thing the set function did was this: `echo "set called";` If you want it to create a property in the class it will also need to do this `this->{$name} = $value`. If that happened in the code __get would have never been called when accessing it.

Comment: No. Expected is that __set is called when protected or private class members are accessed from outside of class. It is not expected that variable handling form outside will change this way. (note that I'm not new to this topic)

Comment: @hek2mgl No. Expected is that `__set` is called on _any assignment to an inaccessible member_, because [that is what the documentation says](http://bg2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set). A non-existent member is certainly inaccessible. You are free to implement the dynamic creation of such properties yourself inside your `__set` method, but if it _did_ happen automatically _before_ the `__set` method is called, you would have had _no way to disable it_.

Comment: @lanzz It is likely that you are right with what you are saying - the inaccessible - sounds logic to me. Thanks.. But I think this can be really a pitfall.. :)

Comment: @hek2mgl The entire PHP language is a pitfall. It tries to prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot by tearing both your feet off with bear traps.

Comment: @lanzz hehe :) coding 12 years PHP but this behaviour is really new to me! thanks for your explanation! (btw, I never tried to create public members from outside on the fly) When I do it I'm implemening __get, __set

Comment: I think the 'trick' here is that, if you do not have a __set implementation, the non-existing field is treated 'public', if you do have one the unexisting field is treated 'private'...

Comment: @KorayTugay Not exactly, in your example, you never declared the property, or assigned a value to a property in your `__set` function

Comment: @datadage But it assumed it was private so it went for the __set directly.. I think it does not matter wheter I  assigned something to it or not. But probably you are right, I am new at this.

Comment: It went into `__set` because a `public` property did not exist. In your case, you never did anything with `$value`, so the state of the object never changed.

Answer (score 4):

`__get` will only be called is no property exists. By removing `__set`, you create a property when setting, so instead of calling `__get`, php just returns the property.

A simple way to think about it is that `__get` and `__set` are error handlers - They kick in, when php can't otherwise honor your request.

Comment: __set is also called only when no property exists right? Or is it called when a private field is trying to be accessed as well?

Comment: @KorayTugay When no `public` property exists. It will get called for `private`, `protected` and non-existant properties.